# Firebase message not opening application when clicking on the notification

Tags: java, android, firebase, pusher

I added the following pice in the manifest to call the onMessageReceived function when a firebase message comes in:

```
<service android:name=".Notifications"
         android:exported="true">
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Here is my onMessageReceive function:

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d("NotificationService", "Notification received!");
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        String deep_link = data.get("deep_link");
        String title = data.get("title");
        String body = data.get("body");
        Log.d("NotificationService", "Notification received!");
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.context.getApplicationContext(), "1");
        builder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
        Intent intent = new Intent(new MainActivity(), Uri.parse(deep_link));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(MainActivity.context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
        builder.setContentTitle(title);
        builder.setContentText(body);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) MainActivity.context.getSystemService(MainActivity.context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            String channelId = "1";
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                    channelId,
                    "1",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            builder.setChannelId(channelId);
        }
        // Will display the notification in the notification bar
        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
    }
```

But the function is never called does someone know where the problem lays?

I tried to send the notification with and without notification payload, tried the app in background state and foreground state, tried killing the app and then sending the notification

When clicking the notification it doesnt open the app or anything

Comment: As you mentioned that ```the function is never called``` there can be several issues as mentioned below

- FCM token is correctly used and not expired 
- your project bundle id is matching with firebase registered and google-service.json file is correct
- api key is correct which is used to send notification
- if you have added SHA key to firebase then check it is matching with your keystore's SHA

Comment: if all things are good to go then try to send notification and check what you are getting in response

to send notification using postman , you can use this article .. postman collection is given

https://medium.com/android-school/test-fcm-notification-with-postman-f91ba08aacc3

Comment: When filling the notification payload i receive a notification but the onMessageReceived is never called i get this log in the logger: I/FCMMessageReceiver: Got a valid pusher message.

Comment: yes because notification payload is handled by firebase SDK that's why not getting called ```onMessageReceived``` in case of notification payload .... try with ```data``` payload instead of notification

Comment: I send a notification with only data payload but the onMessageReceived is still not called

Comment: i hope you have checked every point that i mention in my first comment

Comment: I have checked everything and everything is correct the message is received by the FCMMessageReceiver but the onMessageReceived function i created is never caalled